# hide / show multiple buttons unless relevant field complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a site that allows users to complete form . there are currently 3 text inputs to add username to social media button. if left blank the button should not appear for that specific field , if complete then button will display on users post im having trouble getting this to work it works when using just one field & one button but i need this tow ork over multiple and im unsure on how to achieve this.

/////////////HTML///////////

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control twitter-button" placeholder="Text input">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control github-button" placeholder="Text input">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control facebook-button" placeholder="Text input">
  </div>
</form>


<a class="btn btn-git" href="#" role="button">git button</a>
<a class="btn btn-fb" href="#" role="button">fb button</a>
<a class="btn btn-twitter" href="#" role="button">twitter button</a>
```

//////CSS///////////

```
.btn.btn-twitter {
 display: none;   
}
```

////////JS///////////

```
    $(".twitter-button, .github-button, .facebook-button").keyup(function () {
   if ($(this).val()) {
      $(".btn.btn-default").show();
   }
   else {
      $(".btn.btn-default").hide();
   }
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` gives you the value of the input(returns string). Using it within an `if` directly will not work. **Compare it inside the `if` statement**. Something like `if ($(this).val() == "")`

Comment: Where are buttons?

Comment: apologies forgot to add buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiclInygO3UAhVSalAKHbaYDZ8QFgg1MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ) function and `trim()` will help remove the unwanted space

```js
$(".form-control").keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().trim()) {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find(".btn.btn-default").show();
  } else {
     $(this).closest('.form-group').find(".btn.btn-default").hide();
  }
})
```

```css
.btn.btn-default {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control twitter-button" placeholder="Text input">
     <button class="btn btn-default">default</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control github-button" placeholder="Text input">
     <button class="btn btn-default">default</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control facebook-button" placeholder="Text input">
     <button class="btn btn-default">default</button>
  </div>
 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks this is Perfect!

Comment: @prasad I think its not working for HTML that updated by Dead Respawn

Answer (score 0):

Check all fields on change:

```js
$(".twitter-button, .github-button, .facebook-button").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $(".btn.btn-default").show();
  } else {
    $(".btn.btn-default").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.btn.btn-default {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control twitter-button" placeholder="Text input">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control github-button" placeholder="Text input">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control facebook-button" placeholder="Text input">
  </div>
</form>
```